# Adding views to FrameLayout and animating them

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

What is the best to add a bunch of views to a FrameLayout parent and add animations and interactions to these views programmatically?

For example I want to add some image buttons and move them away after an event bring some other buttons in view, which were out of view initially.

Comment: see ViewGroup.addView() / removeView*() and View.setVisibility()

Answer (score 0):

Check this video, this shows easy examples of different animations which can be applied to most Views :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UWXqFBF86U

Name of the video : DevBytes View Animations

for example for moving around a button use a TranslateAnimation :

```
TranslateAnimation myTranslateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
 // fill in your coordinates from where, to where you want to move it
myTranslateAnimation.setDuration(1000); // Animation plays for 1 sec
myImageButton.startAnimation(myTranslateAnimation);
```